# How to restart console app c# mono MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I use Visual Studio for MacOS.

How to restart console application when i catch exceptions?

Windows code not work:

```
                try
                {

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Process.Start(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
```

Comment: To start an application using mono, you need to run [mono xxx.exe] instead of calling the exe name directly.

Comment: @scegg, "/Users/mac/Projects/Taxi2PartnerMac/Taxi2PartnerMac/bin/Debug/Taxi2PartnerMac.exe"

Comment: sorry I just edited my comment. You can try to start mono as the process and passing this location as argument.

Comment: @scegg, i try to do it

Comment: string path = "mono " + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; Process.Start(path);

Comment: I get exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception - Cannot find the specified file

Comment: it should work if you can start "mono" as process. I think the better way is leaving only mono as the process name, and passing the location as argument. You've got the exception because mono need a location too.

Comment: try /usr/bin/mono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this code for restarting the project but i recommend you to start this project on the .exe it may not work on visual studio.

```
try
{
     //"The code you wanna try"
}
catch
{
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0], Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1 ? string.Join(" ", Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1)) : null);</i>
}
```

Comment: Yes, i run the .exe program from terminal

Comment: the code same works Process.Start(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Environment.Exit(0);